# Overriding a pseudo element in css

Tags: html, css, overriding, styling

I have looked everywhere but cannot seem to find a solution, I have a pseudo element in my css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

and this hides the scroll bar throughout the site, but I would like to override this somehow for one page so that the scroll bar actually display, is there a way to do this? I tried

css:

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="box">
   Page Content<br/>Page Content<br/>Page Content<br/>Page Content<br/>
</div>
```

My alternative solution is to remove this pseudo element and add a class to hide the scroll bar where not needed, but then I would have to alter every individual page, so would hope to find a way to overcome this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with scrollbar, but does adding ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: block;} to your page work?

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } is used so that it is not necessary to reference the class in every html page needed, there is only one page where the scroll bar should show, so what I am looking for is to somehow remove this css element just for one page. If I make it ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: block;}, it will defeat the purpose.

Comment: Yes, but you can target it for the specific page by adding a class to the page body (if using CMD this is probably done automatically), and then override your css for that page only.